# Why Pandas index will keep same when I explode it and How does iloc work in the same index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I find a strange thing. Suppose I have a data frame df1

```
     Children       Father   Mother  Address
  0  Alice|Bob        Tom     Mary    abc
  1   Cathy           Jack    Helen   ddd
```

When I use split("|") and df1.explode("Children")

```
  it will look like 
         Children       Father   Mother  Address
      0   Alice          Tom     Mary    abc
      0    Bob           Tom     Mary    abc
      1   Cathy          Jack    Helen   ddd
```

The index in Alice and Bob are same, however, if I ran print df1.iloc[0, ]

```
it will only print(not "Bob" line)
         Children       Father   Mother  Address
      0   Alice          Tom     Mary    abc
```

if I print df1.iloc[1, ]

```
it will only print
             Children       Father   Mother  Address
          0    Bob           Tom     Mary    abc
```

if I print df1.iloc[2, ]

```
it will print
             Children       Father   Mother  Address
          1   Cathy          Jack    Helen   ddd
```

It is really strange, so I have following questions:
(1).I am confused what is data frame's index meaning here, why I use iloc, it doesn't using the index to choose it
(2). is it possible to make the index(001) to be the normal order like(012)?
(3) I notice the df.append(new_df), the index will look like(0123*012*), but using iloc, it has same thing with the example I did above.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are confusing `loc` and `iloc`.

Comment: `df.explode('Children').reset_index(drop=True)` Use explode and reset_index